# My IP address is not displaying correctly in PHP

Tags: php, get, ip, ip-address

I check my IP address by the http://whatismyipaddress.com/ website. It display my IP address like `203.128.31.58`. But when I get the IP address by using this PHP code

```
echo $ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
```

it displays the IP address like 127.0.0.1. How can I get IP address like `203.128.31.58` and get the country via this IP address?

Comment: Do you know what 127.0.0.1 *is*?  Go pop it into your search engine of choice and be enlightened.

Comment: I'm guessing you are running a local server. `localhost` = `127.0.0.1`

Comment: I don't know this. But I think its my computer address

Comment: yes I am running local server

Comment: but how can I get country by ip address

Comment: @FarazKhan, that is why. The REMOTE_ADDR is the connecting IP address, and if you are connecting locally from same computer it will be the same IP as the server in this case the loopback address.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you upload your code to a live server and fetch the IP address then it will show your public IP address.

And when you run it locally it always shows `127.0.0.1`.

[MaxMind](http://www.maxmind.com/) provides a free PHP GeoIP country lookup class (there is also a free country+city lookup one).

Answer (score 0):

That's because it's showing your localhost IP adress. PHP is ***server*** side, and therefore, the code is running on your machine (localhost), thus showing the IP address 127.0.0.1, localhost.

Answer (score 0):

**Reason:**

It shows `127.0.0.1`, as others have said, because you are opening the website via `http://localhost`.

**Solution:**

If you have some custom domain, link one subdomain (like `test.custom.com`) to your IP address, and configure the webserver to link your page/directory to this domain (`test.custom.com` > `/usr/local/www/site`). Then access the website via this domain (`http://test.custom.com`). Your IP address would be external then.